# How to send a HTTP-delete with a body in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

When I try to create a delete method:

```
public interface ImageService {
    @DELETE("api/v1/attachment")
    Call<BaseResponse> delete(@Body DeleteModel deleteModel);
}
```

I get the error which basically boils down to these lines from the stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body.
```

How can I add a body to a delete method ?

I have searched here but found 3 not answers and nothing using retrofit.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

A more simplified answer.

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "/api/analysis_delete", hasBody = true)
Call<Analysis_Delete_RequestResult_Api10> analysis_delete_api10(@Field("seq") String seq);
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: If you need to send @ Body, you need to remove @ FormUrlEncoded.

Comment: @sunlover3 spot on!

Comment: Totally works, thanks. Btw no need to @FormUrlEncoded as sunlover3 said.

Comment: Appreciate you help,Thank you so much!

Comment: This workaround is throwing an error for me:
"retrofit.RetrofitError: UserService.delete: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @ GET, @ POST, etc.)."

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 20):

Here is my version

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "{login}", hasBody = true)
Call<ResponseBody> getData(@Path("login") String postfix, @Body Map<String, Object> options);
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's an excerpt from the docs, it's a documented feature of the HTTP annotation.

```
This annotation can also used for sending DELETE with a request body:

 interface Service {
   @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "remove/", hasBody = true)
   Call<ResponseBody> deleteObject(@Body RequestBody object);
 }
```

https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/HTTP.html

Answer (score 7):

In case you are you are using an old version that doesn't support @HTTP, you can also add another interface that implements the @RestMethod

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import retrofit.http.RestMethod;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

/** Make a DELETE request to a REST path relative to base URL with body. */
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@RestMethod(value = "DELETE", hasBody = true)
public @interface DELETEWITHBODY {
  String value();
}
```

And then the usage becomes:

```
public interface ImageService {
    @DELETEWITHBODY("api/v1/attachment")
    Call<BaseResponse> delete(@Body DeleteModel deleteModel);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (Kotlin)

for deleting multiple objects (as key-value pair)

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "api/v1/attachment", hasBody = true)
fun getData(@Body requestBody: Map<String, DeleteModel>): Callable<ResponseBody>
```

Or for deleting one object

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "api/v1/attachment", hasBody = true)
fun getData(@Body requestBody: DeleteModel): Callable<ResponseBody>
```

Answer (score 0):

the service:

```
public interface ImageService {
    @Post("api/v1/attachment")
    Call<BaseResponse> delete(@Body DeleteModel deleteModel);
}
```

and in the servercontroller

```
import okhttp3.Request;

private final class ApiInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request oldRequest = chain.request();
        Request.Builder builder = oldRequest.newBuilder();
        if(condition) {
            return chain.proceed(builder.build().newBuilder().delete(builder.build().body()).build());
        }
        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}
```

you have to trigger condition, via something and potentially have to do some filtering for the url/header/body to remove the trigger,

unless the delete url/body/header is unique enough to not collide with post or get requests.

Answer (score 0):

Originally answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62920127/8956093

Kotlin Code :

`path` is not required if your first argument to interface method is a url annotated with @Url
Example :

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", hasBody = true)
fun deleteStudentFromDatabase(
    @Url url: String,
    @Body payload: StudentModel
 ): Observable<Any>
```

If first argument to interface method is not a url then use this

```
    @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "{urlPath}", hasBody = true)
    fun deleteStudentFromDatabase(
        @Body payload: StudentModel,
        @Path("urlPath") url: String
     ): Observable<Any>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I hope it will help others

**I use: Kotlin, Retrofit, Coroutines**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "your_end_point_path", hasBody = true)
suspend fun delete(
    @Field("id") id: String
): Response<BaseResponse<*>>
```